# Possible CORS issue with Windows App

Tags: ajax, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, windows-10-mobile

I have a cordova project in Visual Studio. I need server data which I get by making ajax GET requests. I have fixed CORS issues by adding the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" .../>
```

and my back-end server also responds to CORS requests because I added this line to my web.config:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

My setup WORKS in simulation and on devices for both iOS and Android.

Now I need to do my first Windows app. When I change to build for Windows 10, in debug mode the app never gets any data from the server.

This is my observations:

1. The server does not receive any request from the app.
2. When I press F12 and look at the Network Tab, the request is marked with status 200, although the request is not registered at the server.
3. If I start Fiddler, the app starts to receive data, meaning data is returned to every request.

[image: Developer tools Screenshot]

This screenshot is of the Developer Tools. I press a Refresh button in the app. First 2 entries are made without Fiddler running. Next I start Fiddler and now data is returned. I noticed the "(From Cache)" in the "Received" column, but clicking the "clear cache" button (in dev. tools) does not remove the problem.

Are there any special settings that I might not have set for Windows in Cordova?

**Edit:** Here is some simple source that fails in the same maner. To Reproduce, create a blank Cordova project in Visual Studio, add jQuery, and deploy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: * gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>WinApp</title>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ajaxReq() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://192.168.1.79/',                    
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    success: function (msg, status, jqXHR) {
                        alert('it worked')
                        return true;
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                        alert('it failed')
                        return false;
                    },
                    timeout: 30000
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>

        <button onclick="ajaxReq(); return false;">click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The posted code works if running as a browser simulation for iOS and Android. It fails on Local Machine for Windows builds (x86 & x64).

Comment: Sounds more like a network issue. Did you use any proxy? And have you tried other public web services?

Comment: No proxy, server is in LAN. And I have not given much thought to network issues, since if I simply build for iOS or Android, I have no issues. Are there any special settings for Windows that could be related to this? It's my first build for this platform.

Comment: No special settings except for permission. but since it works well with fiddler open. I don't think it's a permission issue.

Comment: That was why I was thinking CORS, because I imagine fiddler injects itself between the local and external connection making it a local connection seen from the app... (app to fiddler connection)

Comment: And it makes no sense, when 200 status code while the server received nothing. Could you please try to debug see if anything returns?

Comment: When I debug the  behaviour is just like when you have a CORS problem. The Ajax request immediately fails with code 0. And it happens so fast that I am sure that the request was never sent.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the issue? I'll have a try by my side.

Comment: I added some simplified source to the question. I found if I add some external url - e.g. a newspaper, data is loaded. My local server, however, fails => cached results...